# Why my question had been closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

My question has been closed by a moderator. I wonder, why and can it be re-opened?

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9651/new-kind-of-progress

Answer (score 7):

Although dmckee is the one who closed it, this case is obvious enough that I think I can answer: it was closed because

1. it wasn't formulated as an answerable question (you were just asking for opinions)
2. it wasn't precise (you're asking how to do something which you haven't clearly defined)
3. it's unsubstantiated (you allude to some silly-sounding claims about quantum mechanics without providing any believable references)
4. it has nothing to do with physics (that stuff about probability control or that "everybody-wins lottery" sounds totally bogus)

etc. etc.

I see that you've attempted to address point #1, but that doesn't make it either an answerable question or on-topic. So no, it won't be reopened.

Comment: Thanks, David. Bang on.